# how to check if a particular file is present in a directory or not

Tags: ant

I have a jar file in `/programs/src` i want my program to print a message  that it is present in the directory:

```
<if>
    <available file="**/*.jar" />
    <then>
        <echo message="Available" />
    </then>
    <else>
    <echo message="Not Available" />
    </else>
```

but it is not working

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing in the documentation for `<available>` that says it can handle wildcards. You need to use an actual file path.

Comment: but i am working with normal .txt files it is working fine but only if i am giving a complete name of the file

Comment: @user1390517 thats exactly what he said. You can't use wildcards with availeble.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the builtin `${toString:yourfilesetid}` mechanism from ant combined with
 **[Ant Addon Flaka](http://code.google.com/p/flaka/)** like that :

```
<project name="demo" xmlns:fl="antlib:it.haefelinger.flaka">
 <fileset dir="/home/rosebud/temp" includes="**/*.jar" id="foobar"/>
  <fl:choose>
   <fl:when test=" '${toString:foobar}' ne '' ">
    <echo message="Available" />
    <!-- .. other stuff -->
   </fl:when>
   <fl:otherwise>
    <echo message="Not Available" />
    <!-- .. other stuff -->
   </fl:otherwise>
  </fl:choose>
</project>
```